# How to use Messenger as argument in Android IPC

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.1

Basically I want to implement a service that exposes his interface to be used via Android IPC in other apps. The client application should then be able to register a Messenger to receive messages from the service. Since Messenger is Parcelable I thought it should be as simple as:

```
package com.example;
import android.os.Messenger;

interface MyRemoteService {
    void registerMessenger(in Messenger messenger);
}
```

However, I get the error `couldn't find import for class android.os.Messenger`

I asked Google and found a [blog post](http://amdroid.ampache.org/?p=38) from 2010 in which the problem was solved by modifying the `platform/android-<#>/framework.aidl` inside the android sdk so every developer has to modify that file on his/her local machine, which is not a viable solution for me.

Can I register the Messenger in another way that is supported in the Android 7 API (2.1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work using the following method:

Create `Messenger.aidl` with the following contents in package `android.os`:

```
package android.os;

parcelable Messenger;
```

Create your own aidl file like this:

```
package com.example.name;

import android.os.Messenger;

interface IRemoteService {
    void registerMessenger(in Messenger messenger);
}
```

Comment: Interesting that this is still an issue two years after the original post. However your answer is exactly what I was referring to in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6858531/how-to-use-messenger-as-argument-in-android-ipc/19095632?noredirect=1#comment8158408_6859471) to the original answer.

Comment: Your answer was not entirely clear to me, so I thought I'd write it again more clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file titled Messenger.aidl in your project:

```
package com.your.package.here;

parcelable android.os.Messenger;
```

Comment: That almost worked. But taking your advice I created a file Messenger.aidl in src/android/os with the line "parcelable Messenger;" in it. That seems to work, but is that style ok?